# C# standard library 3D int vector

Tags: c#, .net-core

Does the C# standard library contain any type representing a 3D int Vector? I know of `System.Numerics.Vector3` which is a 3D float Vector, but don't know of any int version.

I'm using .NET Core 3 with C# 8.0

Comment: I don't know of any out-of-the-box `int`-based alternative, but why don't you just disregard the decimal part of the `float`-based `Vector3`?

Comment: Primarily because I'll be using it as a way of measuring positions in a grid. When reading from the grid, I'd try to access an array with a float index, which I'd always need to cast to int in order to work.
Also, type safety

Comment: I see. Well, you could use `Vector<int>`, just bear in mind that this is a 8-component vector (in contrast to the 3-component vector that you'd like). So it seems as you would either need to compromise on the type safety side and subsequent casting, or having to consider using the 8D type-safe alternative if you are to use the out-of-the-box vectors. The upside is, of course, that you'd get all the built-in vector operations for free. ;)

Comment: Vector<int>'s size isn't fixed to 8, it might differ from machine to machine depending on the CPU. I don't think it can really go below 3, but I don't exactly want to risk it either

Comment: Thanks for the input, blenderfreaky. I couldn't find the exact doc for the dimensionality of `Vector<T>`, so I assumed from my experiments. I second staying away in that case. Perhaps Math.NET Numerics is a better option for you? Anyways; best of luck. ;)

Comment: Seems sometimes you just have to use a library. I guess it might be better anyways rather than hacking together a solution that uses classes in unintended ways. Thanks!
PS: Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Hehe - done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion linked to your question goes, I'd recommend that you use [Math.NET Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) or similar 3rd party libraries for this.

The built-in alternatives seems to be either

1. Not type-safe, or
2. Subject to variations due to the executing platform

Hence, Math.Net Numerics is probably your best option as of now.